# Why HashMap put so much faster after jdk8?

Tags: hashmap, jvm

Why does this class, built with Java 8, run ~5x faster on Java 11 than Java 8?

```java
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class JMapSpeed {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(10_000_000);

    LocalDateTime start=LocalDateTime.now();

    for (Integer n=0; n< 10_000_000; n++) {
      map.put(n,n);
    }

    LocalDateTime stop= LocalDateTime.now();
    System.out.println("Duration: " + Duration.between(start, stop).toMillis());
    System.out.println("Iterations: " + map.size());
  }
}
```

Comment: Different garbage collector, different heap expansion policy. Give Java 8 more initial heap size and it will execute this example much faster.

Comment: @Holger you're guessing, wrongly. Please try run the code

Comment: I'm wondering if there's an autoboxing optimization going on here. What happens when you add the line `Integer boxed = n;` and then call `map.put(boxed, boxed)`?

Comment: @boneill that improves for both of them but doesnt explain disparity. I've added it in

Comment: @caduceus It's not polite. You've been given a brief exact answer (not a guess) to your question as well as the recommendation to run the code faster on JDK 8. If the answer wasn't clear enough, you could kindly ask for clarification. I did run your code and can confirm that Holger's answer is correct. Hint: add `-verbose:gc` to see what's happening.

Comment: ok im sorry i don't know how to use java command line arguments

Comment: You can use the `-Xms` option to set the initial heap size and `-Xmx` to set the maximum heap size. E.g., when I use `-Xmx2g -Xms2g` on my machine with Java 8, it runs as fast as Java 11 with default options. Giving it even more heap memory will make it even faster. You can also use `-XX:+UseG1GC` to select the same garbage collection algorithm as Java 11 uses by default, however, the newer Java version has (of course), a newer implementation of this algorithm, so there will be some differences, even when using exactly the same configuration.

Comment: How do you start your program when you’re not using the command line?

Comment: @Holger I only use cli args, but with java their position matters. I see Shenandoah even increases the speed 3x over G1C1. This code was used as a demonstration of why we need to upgrade our existing production to jdk11. I just wanted to make sure there was no easier change we could make, like using a different GC. My only Q now is how contrived is the example and whether it really represents what the runtime is doing

Comment: The example is contrived, but sometimes, it’s helpful to show extremes, even when you know that your real application will not be affected to such a degree. As said, higher initial heap size or selecting G1GC can improve the Java 8 performance as well. However upgrading still makes a lot of sense. If you want to demonstrate this, *use strings*. Real life applications have a lot of them and Java 9 introduced compact strings (ascii & latin-1 strings consume half the memory) which can have a dramatic impact. And G1GC has helpful string deduplication (activate with `-XX:+UseStringDeduplication`).